# The function $f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$ maps $\Omega$ biholomorphically on the upper plane

Tags: complex-analysis

The question states:

> Let $\Omega$ be the upper half plane minus the unit disk. Show that the map $f: z \mapsto z+1/z$ maps $\Omega$ biholomorphically on the upper plane. Describe the preimages of the lines $\mathrm{Im}(z)=\text{a constant}>0$.

So how exactly does one show the mapping is biholomorphic. I'm not sure where I should start, so unfortunately I haven't made any progress

Comment: Recall: A mapping is biholomorphic iff it is holomorphic and its inverse is, too.

Comment: Per definition, a biholomorphic function is a bijective holomorphic function with a holomorphic inverse. Show that the function is bijective and holomorphic, find its inverse and show that it is also holomorphic. As for the image of the function, note that the domain is simply connected and hence the image must be simply connected too; therefore all you have to do is show that the image of the boundary is the x-axis, and a point in the domain mapped to the upper plane.

Answer (score 2):

If $z_1\ne z_2$ and $|z_1|, |z_2|>1$, then 
$$\left|\frac{1}{z_2}-\frac{1}{z_1}\right| = \frac{|z_1-z_2|}{|z_1||z_2|}<|z_1-z_2| \tag1$$
hence 
$$\frac{1}{z_2}-\frac{1}{z_1}\ne z_1-z_2 \tag2$$
This gives injectivity.

Using polar coordinates $z=re^{it}$, we find that $\operatorname{Im}(1/z)=-|z|^{-2}\operatorname{Im}z  = -r^{-1}\sin t$. So, the curve $\operatorname{Im}(z+1/z)=a$ can be written as 
$$(r-r^{-1})\sin t=a$$
which can be solved for $r$ or for $t$. Either way, you will see that along the curve 
$$\operatorname{Re}(z+1/z) =(r+r^{-1})\cos t$$ takes on all real values, being continuous and unbounded in both directions. This implies surjectivity as a by-product.