# Question about the biholomorphic mapping $w = z+\frac{a^2}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to do the "show this" in this example:
[image]

But I'm a bit stuck. Is there a fast way to do this? I tried by writing:
$$ w = x+iy = z+\frac{a^2}{z}$$
And solving for $z$, which after some calculations gives me:
$$
z_{1} = \frac{x+iy+\sqrt{x^2-y^2-4a^2+2ixy}}{2}
$$
$$
z_{2} = \frac{x+iy-\sqrt{x^2-y^2-4a^2+2ixy}}{2}
$$
My goal was now to prove that (when I require that $y > 0$) exactly one of the two solutions lies in $\Omega$. But I don't really see how I can do this. I hope some can help me out. Please also tell if there is a better/faster way to do this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is the composition of

1. $z\mapsto z/a$, which scales the disk down to the the unit disk
2. $z\mapsto z+1/z$, [Joukowsky transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform)
3. $z\mapsto az$ which scales things up.

The only non-obvious step is the second, which is explained in [The function $f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$ maps $\Omega$ biholomorphically on the upper plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355742/).