# What is the image of D under the map $f(z)=bz+\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, mobius-function

Let $f:\mathbb C_\infty\to   \mathbb C_\infty$ be a sum of Mobius transformations defined by  $f(z)=bz+\frac{1}{z}$, where  $-1<b<1$.

I've succeeded to find the image of the unit closed disc $D$ under the both of  Mobius transformations  $f_1(z)=bz$ and  $f_2(z)=\frac{1}{z}$  individually.

But, I failed to find $f(D)$.

**Question :** Find $f(D)$. Is it true that  $f(D)$ is a subset of $\mathbb C-D$?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1077207/42969 – your function can be decomposed  in a quite similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counter example**

For $-1<b<0$, consider$$z_0={1\over \sqrt {1-b}}\implies |z_0|<1$$therefore$$f(z_0)=bz_0+{1\over z_0}=z_0$$

**P.S.**

This transformation maps the circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$to the ellipse $${x^2\over b+{1\over r^2}}+{y^2\over b-{1\over r^2}}=r^2$$

Comment: This  $f$ is not in the required form here.

Comment: Because $f$ is not a sum of dilation and inversion.

Comment: By $z$ I meant a specific $z$ but you are right. I fixed it :)